# Unable to spread elements in Bootstrap to the edges

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to spread the elements across to the corner of the screen. I did try making use of the following code, but it isn't working.

```
<!-- Page Footer -->
<footer>
<div class="navbar mt-3 py-3 bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <small class="text-white">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span class="text-white">Copyright &copy; my website 2020</span>
      <a class="text-white" href="{% url 'privacy-policy' %}">Privacy Policy</a>
    </div>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

This is how it is apprearing:

I would like to have the Copyright text and Privacy Policy spread across the edges of the screen
[image: I would like to have the Copyright text and Privacy Policy spread across the edges of the screen]

Comment: <small> is an inline element so it doesn't span the 100% width... try using a block level element like <div> instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<small>` is an inline element so it doesn't span the 100% width... try using a block level element like `<div>` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/small

You should also make sure width is set to 100% on this element.

```
<!-- Page Footer -->
<footer>
<div class="navbar mt-3 py-3 bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="width:100%;" class="text-white">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span class="text-white">Copyright &copy; my website 2020</span>
      <a class="text-white" href="{% url 'privacy-policy' %}">Privacy Policy</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
```